# gv: the outputs of pdflatex, latex+dvipdf, and latex+ps2pdf are slightly shifted upwards compared to the output of latex+dvips

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, geometry, ghostscript, postscript

Let's create mwe.tex containing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=1cm,paperheight=1.25cm,margin=0cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw](A){};
  \node[draw,below of=A]{};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

and run `latex mwe && pdflatex mwe && dvips -o mwe.ps mwe.dvi && dvipdf mwe.dvi mwe.dvi.pdf && ps2pdf mwe.ps mwe.ps.pdf` on Debian. Below, we see mwe.ps, mwe.pdf,  mwe.dvi.pdf, and mwe.ps.pdf (from left to right), shown by the viewer gv.  As we see, in the PostScript output, the upper box is fully visible, whereas in the PDF output, the upper line of the upper box is cut off:

[image: two-box output]

If we remove the lower `\node…` command from the input, the upper box becomes fully visible, but the Postscript and PDF output are still different:

[image: one-output]

In the Postscript, the remaining box is lower than in the PDF.

Clearly, cutting off stuff is unwished (as well as discrepancies between the Postscript and PDF outputs in general). Why does this happen, who is the culprit, and what to do?

Warning: this question is specific to the viewer gv! In other viewers, discrepancies and unexpected behavior also occur, but they are of different nature.  Let's not overcomplicate the matter and handle the viewers separately.

Crosspost: http://bugs.debian.org/1036112.

Comment: compiled with a current texlive and viewed in adobe reader and sumatra and the pdf viewer from winedt the boxes are exactly in the corner, so I would say it is probably a gv problem and you should report it there.

Comment: @Ulrike Thx! Bug report submitted: http://bugs.debian.org/1036112 .